# What tier are the Pathfinder classes at 1-10 levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

i seen a lot of tiers list that say 9th level spellcasters are absolutely best.. but most of the games PFS i seen are going at levels 1-10, so i think this theoretical tiers are just not working at this levels, but what classes would you say are strongest at 1-10 and why?

Comment: Welcome to this stack! Take the [tour]! I think this question may already be answered by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96598/8610); please take a look at it and see if it addresses this question's issue, and, if it doesn't, please edit this question to be more specific. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, mobile editing is causing problems here. I wanted that one to be first, but it’s just not happening.